# Rewrite rule in htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rule

Here are the `.htaccess` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ content.php?seourl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pdf/([^/]*)$ content-single.php?seourl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^browsepdf$ browse.php [L]
RewriteRule ^browsepdf-([^/]*)$ browse.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*)$ download.php?pdf=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ xmlsitemap.php [L]

Options -Indexes
```

Here every URL is pointing to `content.php?seourl=$1`, even css, js and image files.

Here are some example URLs I need,

```
http://example.com/sjskjfsk21
http://example.com/asfasfasf43sf
http://example.com/pdf/fhfdhdh3432aaf
http://example.com/pdf/aisfyiahm2faf3
http://example.com/browsepdf
http://example.com/browsepdf-1
http://example.com/browsepdf-2
http://example.com/download/fjaskfjalsk3rs
http://example.com/download/usaydiy7aisydi
http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Can anyone please fix the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here every url is pointing to "content.php?seourl=$1"

Because your first (generic) rule catches all the requests. You need to change the order so you have the *most specific* rules first, and the most generic (catch-all) rules at the end. In your case you just need to move the first rule to the end. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^pdf/([^/]*)$ content-single.php?seourl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^browsepdf$ browse.php [L]
RewriteRule ^browsepdf-([^/]*)$ browse.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*)$ download.php?pdf=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ xmlsitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ content.php?seourl=$1 [L]
```

NB: I backslash-escaped the dot in `sitemap.xml` to match a literal dot, otherwise it matches *any* character.

> even css, js and image files.

You can make an *exception* for these static resources at the beginning of your file, before the existing directives. For example:

```
RewriteRule \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ - [L]
```

For any URL that ends in any of the stated file extensions then stop processing the current mod_rewrite rules.

Alternatively (although perhaps marginally less efficient), you can prevent processing of requests for files that exist. Again, this goes before your existing mod_rewrite directives. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

However, this must now check *every* request for the existence of a file on the filesystem that maps to the request. (It could also be combined with the above rule if required.)

**UPDATE:** Bringing this together, we have:

```
# Exclude any existing files from being rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Specific rewrites
RewriteRule ^pdf/([^/]*)$ content-single.php?seourl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^browsepdf$ browse.php [L]
RewriteRule ^browsepdf-([^/]*)$ browse.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*)$ download.php?pdf=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ xmlsitemap.php [L]

# Any other requests for the form "/<anything>"
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ content.php?seourl=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok. Let me try this

Comment: Can you please put the full code with alternative method?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is perfect.